# Фраза с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нет ли ошибки в данном примере: "Они целовались под шелест листьев, предвкушая предстоящий рассвет"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборот на месте; режет глаз ПРЕДвкушая ПРЕДстоящий. Со смыслом напряжёнка.